# Run time error "1004" copy of object worksheet failed

Tags: excel, vba

I'm stuck with this problem:
I tried to save a memo template with macro in. But when I open the new Excel, the memo template follows but not the code. Therefore I save the memo template as Excel addins. However when I assign the macro to the button, there is the error message:

> Run time error "1004" copy of object worksheet failed

[image]

```
Sub Test()
    Dim ws1 As Worksheet
    Set ws1 = ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("Sample1")
    ws1.Copy ThisWorkbook.Sheets(Sheets.Count)

    Dim Sheetname As String
    With ActiveSheet
        Sheetname = InputBox("Enter name of this Worksheet")
        .Name = Sheetname
    End With 
End Sub
```

The line with error msg is `ws1.Copy ThisWorkbook.Sheets(Sheets.Count)`

The excel file name is `book1.xlsm`

[image]

Comment: You probably need to change `ThisWorkbook` to `ActiveWorkbook`. `ThisWorkbook` is the workbook this code is running at (so probably your add-in). `ActiveWorkbook` is the workbook that has the focus and is on top at the moment the code is running.

Comment: What are you trying to achieve? Is it to copy a sheet from your template to a new workbook? not sure what the end goal is here

Comment: Does specifying whether you want to copy your worksheet `Before` or `After` `ThisWorkbook.Sheets(Sheets.Count)` fix the problem?